# JNI values assignment to array

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have this array of jvalue type and I want to assign string values.

I'm on unity trying to pass parameters to my Java function using JNI library

```
  jvalue[] myArray = new jvalue[2];
        myArray[0]="abcd";
        myArray[1]="khan";
        gui.text=   AndroidJNI.CallStaticStringMethod(obj_Activity, startAdsMethod, myArray);
```

How to achieve the code above?

I'm getting the error whilst assigning values to the array because the array is not of string type my function takes string parameters and jni wants them in form of array.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a Mind Reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551)

Answer (score 1):

The following code creates an array and assigns a few strings to use in any following JNI calls:

```
var arguments = new object[2];
foreach( var entry in variables ) {
    using( var key = new AndroidJavaObject( "java.lang.String", entry.Key ) ){
        using( var val = new AndroidJavaObject( "java.lang.String", entry.Value ) ){
            arguments[0] = key;
            arguments[1] = val;
                    [... do something with the array ...]
        }
    }
}
```